# get selected row pyqt5 qttablewidget

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a very simple application using pyqt5, I have a tableWidget with 5 rows the first row is hidden that has the ID from MySQL database. I want to make rows clickable and when clicked I need to check the hidden comlumn in order to retreive the information from mysql based on it's ID in order to modify or delete the row below is the function I used to get information from mysql into tablewidget

```
    def loaddata(self):
    self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM urltable")
    rows = self.cur.fetchall()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for row_number, row_data in enumerate(rows):
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
```

Comment: so you want to know which row got selected or what is your exact desire? Examples are allways great ;)

Comment: I have a hidden column storing in it the id from mysql I need to retreive this id whenever I doubled click on any row

Answer (score 2):

*unless you give us some examples I can just guess what you want:*

```
def valueFromFirstColumnOfCurrentlySelectedRow():
    row = self.tableWidget.currentRow() # Index of Row
    firstColumnInRow = self.tableWidget.item(row, 0) # returns QTableWidgetItem
    text = firstColumnInRow.text() # content of this
    return int(text) # if this is a index, you propably dont want it as text
```

Comment: replace the `0` with whatever the index of your hidden column is

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for

Comment: @FadyGhalayiny: feel free to mark the question as completed then